# GNU Parallel: How do determine job "slot" you're using?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to find a way to determine the job "slot" or "core" a command is currently using in `parallel`. For example, we've all seen a similar image of how `parallel` distributes commands:

[image]

If I want to know which column a certain process is in, how do I know?

My specific problem illustrated: if set `-j 4` to only allow 4 jobs to run at once, I want to dynamically know which slot a command is taking, 1 2 3 or 4. The problem is I have some commands that cannot run in parallel, but if I knew which slot I was running in, I'm all good.

Further example, say I have these commands I'm parallelizing:

```
command resource1 file1.rb
command resource2 file2.rb
command resource3 file3.rb
command resource4 file4.rb
command resource1 file5.rb
command resource2 file6.rb
command resource3 file7.rb
command resource4 file8.rb
```

Only one command can use each resource at a time. Say I put these commands in `parallel` like usual with 4 jobs at a time, and job 3 finishes up and it goes to the next in the queue, I now have these running in parallel:

```
command resource1 file1.rb
command resource2 file2.rb
command resource3 file3.rb
command resource1 file5.rb
```

Notice `resource1` is being used by two commands, not good. What I need is an environment variable or something to tell the next command to use resource number 4, so that the parallelized commands looks like this:

```
command resource1 file1.rb
command resource2 file2.rb
command resource3 file3.rb
command resource4 file5.rb
```

I've thought about using the filesystem or some other kind of external signs of which resources are in use, but I figure with parallel processes, there are likely to be race conditions going that route.

I've looked all over, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for {%}:

```
parallel -j4 command ressource{%} file{}.rb ::: {1..8}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks to be it!! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much!